# Is there a way to set the "select" options on a per-cell or per-row basis within a column in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I would like to know if there is a way to set the `Tabulator` select options by both row and column?  For example, the following `Tabulator` table setup contains a column definition with a "select" editor and parameters:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#myDiv"), {
    height: "100%",
    data: [],
    columns: [
        { title: "Project ID", field: "Projectid", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: { values: projectIdList } },
        { title: "Phase Code", field: "Phasecode", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "select", editorParams: { values: laborPhaseCodes } } 
    ]
});
```

The `"select" editor` refers to an array to acquire its `values` inside the `editorParams`.  This creates the same dropdown list of options for each row/cell in the `Phasecode` column.

What I would like to do is populate the `values` list with a set of options applicable to the selected value from the `Projectid` column on a row-by-row basis.  Stated differently, the `Projectid` code will be different for each row and the `Phasecode` options are unique for each `Projectid`.  Consequently, when the user makes a `Projectid` selection, I would like to refresh the `Phasecode` options for that row only.

Can it be done?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer in the `Tabulator` documentation.  Yes, it is possible to trigger each cell in a column to load its own list of options.  From the `Tabluator` documentation:

```
editorParams: function (cell) { return { values: myArray}; }
```